# What is the standard way to get the active (running) D3 v3 Transition for a given element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

The abstractions of D3 still make my mind bend, so hopefully I'm presenting this correctly.

In D3 **version 3**, given an element (say a circle), and [given only one transition possibly running per element](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/#per-element) what is the best way to determine what the current running transition on that element is, if there is one at all?

I'm aware that I can manually inspect `__transition__` on the element (though help there is welcome too), but I'm really hoping for something a little higher-level.

My larger goal here is to create a subtransition if-and-only-if there's a transition to sub.  Otherwise, I'll be creating a new transition.

Comment: Can you specify if you are talking about v2 or v3?

Comment: I said version 3, but maybe I should bold it or something..

Comment: Inspecting \_transition_ is probably the most efficient way to do it. The \_transition_ property is removed after the transition on an element ends, so, you could simply do a check to see if the \_transition_ property is present. If it is, you know there is a transition happening on that element,and you can check \_transition_ to get more detailed information. You also have options for grabbing sub-elements of the transition element, such as using transition.selectAll(). You could also add listeners to each element in transition using transition.each()

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:  Create your own property on each node that stores an array of the actual `d3.transition` objects.  When creating a new transition, grab the last transition from the array and create a sub-transition.

The complication is that your new transition may not be based on the same selection as the active transition.  Therefore, I create the new "safe" transitions on a per-element basis within an `.each()` call.

```
function saveTransition(t) {
    //save the transition immediately (don't wait for "start")
    //clear it on "end"
    t.each(function() {
        var tArr = this.__tObj__
        if (!tArr) tArr = this.__tObj__ = [];

        tArr.push(t);
        //console.log("saving ", t, " for ",this);
      } )
     .each("end", function() {
        var test =  this.__tObj__.shift();
        // console.log("clearing ", t, " from " ,this, 
         //            (test == t ? "correctly" : "ERROR") );
       } );
}
function newSafeTransition(node) { 
    var tArr = node.__tObj__; 
    if ( tArr && tArr.length ) {

        var t = tArr[ tArr.length - 1 ];
        return t.filter( function(){ return this === node; } )
                .transition().call(saveTransition);
    }
    else {
        return  d3.select(node).transition().call(saveTransition);
    }
}

d3.selectAll("div.foo")
    .transition().duration(3000)
    .call( saveTransition )
    .style("left", "100px");

d3.selectAll("div.bar")
    .transition().duration(3000)
    .call( saveTransition )
    .style("top", "100px");

setTimeout( function() { 
    console.log("blue");

    d3.selectAll("div.blue")
      .each( function() {
            newSafeTransition(this).style("color", "blue");
        });
}, 1000);

setTimeout( function() { 
    console.log("reposition");

    d3.selectAll("div.foo")
      .each( function() {
            newSafeTransition(this).style("left", "0px");
        });
}, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7SQBe/3/

It could probably be cleaned up, you could even over-write the `selection.transition()` and `transition.transition()` methods to do this automatically.  However, you'd probably want to keep a way to indicate whether you want to queue the new transition after any scheduled transitions or whether you want to interrupt.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that there's no standard way to get the transition and you're not meant to do that. As in, it's not supported.

The slightly longer answer is that for your purposes, you can probably hack it using `__transition__`. The idea is to check whether `__transition__` exists and if so, wait until it doesn't before starting the new (sub)transition.

To do that, it helps to extend the selection prototype with an appropriate function:

```
d3.selection.prototype.getTransition = function() {
  if(this[0][0].__transition__) {
    return this[0][0].__transition__[1];
  } else return undefined;
}
```

Note that this here is *extremely hacky* and will *only* work if there is *exactly one element in the selection* with *exactly one transition*. You should get the idea though.

Now, we can use this function to determine whether a transition is running.

```
if(sel.getTransition() !== undefined) {
  // transition is there
} else {
  // no transition
}
```

Unfortunately, `__transition__` does not allow you to reconstruct the transition object, i.e. the following won't work.

```
sel.getTransition().transition()...
```

So to simulate a subtransition that starts after the currently running one is complete, use `setTimeout` to check whether something is running and as soon as nothing is, start your new transition:

```
function check() {
  if(sel.getTransition() !== undefined) {
    setTimeout(check, 100);
  } else {
    sel.transition().duration(1000)...;
  }
}
check();
```

You can reduce the interval between checks (100ms here) to create a better impression of a transition that immediately follows the previous one.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7SQBe/). Note that in almost all cases, it's far easier and better to keep a reference to the transition object somewhere and use that. This example really only serves as a hacky proof of concept.

Comment: Interesting problem.  You can make it a little more efficient by using the properties of the `__transition__[1]` object to calculate exactly when the current transition will end, and set your timeout accordingly:  http://jsfiddle.net/7SQBe/1/