# When running a D3 update/enter/exit, how to ignore already exiting elements during the new exit?

Tags: d3.js, transition, updates, exit

Everyone knows the update/enter/exit pattern:

```
function update(data) {

  // DATA JOIN
  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data);

  // UPDATE
  // Update old elements as needed.
  text.attr("class", "update");

  // ENTER
  // Create new elements as needed.
  text.enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 32; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

  // ENTER + UPDATE
  // Appending to the enter selection expands the update selection to include
  // entering elements; so, operations on the update selection after appending to
  // the enter selection will apply to both entering and updating nodes.
  text.text(function(d) { return d; });

  // EXIT
  // Remove old elements as needed.
  text.exit().transition().duration(2000).attr('transform',
    rotation = 25;
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ') rotate('+ rotation +' 30 30)';
  }).remove();
}
```

My question is:

If I run this function while the exit is still occurring (during the 2000 ms transition window), how can I prevent the transition being called on elements already undergoing the `exit` transition.

In other words, when the original selection is made, it includes elements already in the `exit().transition()` state. So the exit transition is called on these elements a second time if they are not finished with their transition and `removed()`.

Would I need to make a filter? Is there a test for `in transition while exiting`?

Answer (score 5):

[D3.js: Stop transitions being interrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335781/d3-js-stop-transitions-being-interrupted)
says give the exiting element a special class and then use that to only admit freshly exiting elements to the exit transition

```
.exit()
     .filter(function(d,i) {
        return !d3.select(this).classed("exiting");
     })
     .classed("exiting", true)
     .transition()
     ...
```

A bigger problem will be any data that's re-introduced on your second click while it's still subject to an exit transition from the first. This in your example would disappear elements you want to keep as the exit transition finishes and calls a remove on that element. To get round this in the past I've added immediate (zero delay, zero duration) transitions to my update and enter selections to override/write the exit selection, if they don't have their own transitions already (if there's a better way someone let me know).

This leads to another point: set `.classed("exiting", false)` in the enter and update, so in the case of 'exiting'>'re-introduced'>'exiting again' elements the .exiting class isn't set and the exiting transition is activated.

Comment: I really dislike this solution. It uses classes a bit carelessly for my tastes. There must be some way in which you can test whether an element is in the exit process, or so I'd hope.

Comment: Well, you could add flags to the data set instead, .each (function(d,i) { d.exiting = true; }) and then test for that in the filter, but some might not like that either - especially if the data is involved in multiple views. In the end classes are nothin' special :-). It does appear there's no clean, i.e. api, method to ask if an element is involved in a transition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844179/what-is-the-standard-way-to-get-the-active-running-d3-v3-transition-for-a-give